# Struts2 - REST Controllers from external jar files issue

Tags: struts2

Needed to update to Struts 2.3.12 (along with all dependencies).
Now I can't get the REST interface to work. As the controllers are located in an external jar file.

In the previous version of struts2, the following constant was set in struts.properties:

```
struts.convention.action.includeJars = .*/myJar-Rest(.*)?.jar(!/)?
```

And was working properly.

Now, I'm not being able to get the rest plugin to work. It fails to load the actions in the external jar. Which is in the classpath.

**output in startup:**

```
2013-03-24 00:18:23,957 [org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder]   
WARN - <The includeJars pattern [.*/myJar-Rest(.*)?.jar(!/)?] did not match any 
jars in the classpath>
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: What version were you using previously? What container? Are you deploying an EAR or WAR? There were a couple of changes in 2.3.12 relating to jar files and the convention plugin.

Comment: As @DaveNewton asked, need more details, also try to remove .jar

Comment: Hi, the previous configuration was:
struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-rest-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar

Comment: About the deployment: It's a modular where all the java classes get jar packaging and are copied to the /WEB-INF/lib/ folder on the "main" - web - project. The build and deployment server, allied with our enterprise deployment's guidelines, are set to deploy everything with versioned jar files. (for the time being, I've managed to edit the build.xml, so the build server only copies the .class files into /WEB-INF/classes/. But this is just a workaround to keep the development REST module to work. Thanks a lot.